# Pandas subtraction behavior having precision issues (even after casting)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Maybe this was answered before, but I'm trying to understand what is the best way to work with Pandas subtraction.

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

random.seed(42)
data = {'r': list([float(random.random()) for i in range(5)])}
for i in range(5):
    data['r'].append(float(0.7))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If I run the following, I get the expected results:

```py
print(np.sum(df['r'] >= 0.7))
6
```

However, if I modify slightly the condition, I don't get the expected results:

```py
print(np.sum(df['r']-0.5 >= 0.2))
1
```

The same happens if I try to fix it by casting into `float` or `np.float64` (and combinations of this), like the following:

```py
print(np.sum(df['r'].astype(np.float64)-np.float64(0.5) >= np.float64(0.2)))
1
```

For sure I'm not doing the casting properly, but any help on this would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything improperly. This is a totally straightforward floating point error. It will always happen.

```
>>> 0.7 >= 0.7
True
>>> (0.7 - 0.5) >= 0.2
False
```

You have to remember that floating point numbers are represented in binary, so they can only represent sums of powers of 2 with perfect precision. Anything that can't be represented finitely as a sum of powers of two will be subject to error like this.

You can see why by forcing Python to display the full-precision value associated with the literal `0.7`:

```
format(0.7, '.60g') 
'0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875'
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @senderle answer, since this is a floating point issue you can solve it by:

`((df['r'] - 0.5) >= 0.19).sum()`

Oh a slightly different note, I'm not sure why you use `np.sum` when you could just use pandas `.sum`, seems like an unnecessary import